# What is wrong with this simple `-flattenMap` ReactiveCocoa code?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

After reading the README on `-flattenMap` several times I still can't figure out why this code isn't executing as expected.  I should think that the code inside the block would be run twice but it's not getting hit at all.  Am I missing something really silly?  (I'm using v2.4.7)  I also tried sending the values after I called `-flattenMap` in case it's an order thing.  No dice.

```
RACSubject *test = [[RACSubject alloc] init];
[test sendNext:@1];
[test sendNext:@2];
[test sendCompleted];
[test flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
  NSLog(@"here: %@", value);
  return [RACSignal return:@NO];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

The order does matter, since this is a subject, so change it to this:

```
RACSubject *test = [[RACSubject alloc] init];
[test flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
    NSLog(@"here: %@", value);
    return [RACSignal return:@NO];
}];
[test sendNext:@1];
[test sendNext:@2];
[test sendCompleted];
```

Now, you're still not going to see anything -- because you haven't subscribed to it. You have merely created a signal that *can* do all this, but it's going to delay actually doing any work until you ask for it.

```
RACSubject *test = [[RACSubject alloc] init];
[[test flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
    NSLog(@"here: %@", value);
    return [RACSignal return:@NO];
}] subscribeNext:^(id value) {
    NSLog(@"got a %@", value);
}];
[test sendNext:@1];
[test sendNext:@2];
[test sendCompleted];
```

Now, since there's a subscriber who actually wants to know about values, those `send`s will trigger as appropriate.

In the future, avoid putting side effects (like logging) anywhere except the blocks of the `subscribe*` and `do*` family of methods. `flattenMap` and other combinators want to be pure, so you'll see unexpected behavior like this if you violate that.

You probably know this, and are just testing out `flattenMap`, but your code can be simplified to just a `map` here -- `flattenMap` + `return` == `map`.

Comment: Facepalm.  Yeah this makes sense and thanks a ton.  So just to make sure I have my terms correct, is this behavior a reflection of it being a hot signal or is that a different concept entirely?

Comment: @eremzeit I believe that's right, but inverted. The signal you derived -- with `flattenMap` -- is a *cold* signal. It doesn't do anything until someone subscribes to it. It's weird to talk about hot vs. cold signals when they are (or should be) completely pure like this, though -- I think a more appropriate example is something like a network request. If you create a hot signal representing a GET request, the request is performed whether or not someone subscribes to it. A cold GET signal, though, would wait for someone to "ask for" the result of the request to kick off the request.